# Azure DevOps: get and pass Unix time as a variable

Tags: azure-devops

I need to get Unix time (to control test start time and finish time) and send these in the email after the test finish.
I use the following Powershell code to get Unix time:

```
$unixEpochStart = new-object DateTime 1970,1,1,0,0,0,([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
$unixTestStart = [int]([DateTime]::UtcNow - $unixEpochStart).TotalSeconds
Write-Host $unixTestStart
```

Then in Send an email task I have the following:

```
Test started at ($(unixTestStart)), test finished at ($(unixTestFinish))
```

As a result I see the following:

```
Test started at(), test finished at ()
```

I've tried also `$(unixTestStart)`, `($[unixTestFinish])`, but this did not give the result.

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use PowerShell inline build task?

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander yes, I use inline PowerShell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You properly did not use below statement [set variables in script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1). Please check below script to set the `unixTestStart` and  `unixTestFinish` to environment variables.

```
$unixEpochStart = new-object DateTime 1970,1,1,0,0,0,([DateTimeKind]::Utc)
$unixTestStart = [int]([DateTime]::UtcNow - $unixEpochStart).TotalSeconds

#set the value of $unixTestStart to environ variable unixTestStart

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=unixTestStart]$unixTestStart"
```

Then use the same statement to set the `unixTestFinish` to environment variables.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=unixTestFinish]$unixTestFinish"
```

Then you should be able to refer to them by `$(unixTestStart), $(unixTestFinish)` in the send emails tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your are trying to use the build variable that was not assigned - $(unixTestStart). Check this manual to assign variables: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-in-script)

Here is my example:

1. The variable in the build definition:

[image]

2. Update value:

[image]

3. Check variable

[image]

The build result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question was how to pass this Unix time to Send an email task. Powershell script which I provided in my question returns the required number: `2020-01-04T09:38:20.1327795Z 1578130700`

Comment: @user270219  You need to set the start time and end time to env variable using syntax '##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes'. So that you can refer to them in your send email task.

Comment: I've assigned variables `unixEpochStart`,  `unixTestStart` and `unixtestStartValueToAssign`. I've used code provided by @Shamrai Aleksander, but the result is the same: `Test started at(), test finished at ()`

Comment: @user270219 What extension do you use to send email?

Comment: @Shamrai Aleksander I'm using the following expression in mail body: Test started at $(unixtestStartValueToAssign) (Send email task in AzureDO)